# Determine whether a graph has a unique max flow

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Is there a characterization result/some sufficient conditions that ensure that a graph has a unique max flow?

Note that it does not say anything about the min-cuts: a path with all edges having weight 1 has a unique max-flow, but many min cuts.

I believe that it is sufficient that in all optimal solutions of the maximum flow we have that all edges have some positive flow through them. Is that the case?

Comment: What do you mean "unique" max flow?

Comment: It should be sufficient that all cuts which separate the source and sink are min cuts. However, this is not necessary.

Comment: @vadim123 I just mean that there is only one flow $f^*$ in that maximizes the flow in the graph (not to be confused with the statement that the value of the max flow is unique...)

Comment: @PeterTaylor this is a rather strong requirement. But thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample to your conjecture:[image]